# Are there any better method other than using Timer to make my card reader detect for a card?

Tags: c#, timer, rfid, reader

I'm developing a software that using `RFID card reader` (**ACR120U**).

I coded my reader to detect card by using `Timer`.

Every `tick`, my reader will read a card's UID. If it found a UID, it means it found a card and do stuff but if it cannot read UID, it does nothing.

**Here's a sample code**:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      cardListener.Start();  // Start the Timer.
}       

private void cardListener_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      _Key = StringToByteArray(KeyInString);  // Assign card access key.
      cardUID = rfidLib.ReadUID(Convert.ToByte(0), Convert.ToByte(0), _Key);

      // Read card's UID. If it detects valid UID, that means 
      // it found a card. Otherwise, do nothing
      if (cardUID != "0")
      {
           // Do things.
      }
}
```

Technically, it works but I'm not sure if this is a good way.

Can anybody suggests other methods for me?

Comment: I would imagine something like that would be dependant on the API that you are using and if it supports such a requirement

Comment: What other functions does the rfidlib provide?

Comment: As far as i see it , timer is the best option .... what is the issue with timers u are facing ?

Comment: Unrelated: I'd separate that from your UI code. Does the library provide some sort of callback or event you can register for? Reacting to a RFID reading feels predestined to using an event driven design to me.

Comment: @pritaeas Not much. Here it goes, read card data from selected sector and block, write data to a card, play beep sound from the reader, edit access key and return card reader's name.

I'm not sure if the `rfidlib` is an official or self-made library because I got it from the previous developer who did this project. Previously, he makes the program read a card by clicking a button and fire "read card" function. But I need to make it continuously seeks for a card.

Comment: @zackraiyan No issue at all. I'm just new at this so I'm curious if it good or bad.

Comment: If there is no event for when a card is seen, then a timer is the only thing you can do I suppose.

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for the suggestion. Actually, my application is running in the background and show no form. The library has no event code, just functions to interact with the reader (Read card/Write card/Beeping and others)

Comment: In that case it could be worth looking into the lib. If it is indeed self-made you may want to add an event, so your application can be notified instead of polling.

Comment: @VeerakranSereerungruangkul I have a handy solution that takes care of all of the functionalities you listed. I have developed using Mifare Ultralight and Ultralight C